# How to create servlet filter to authorize the request?

Tags: spring

How to create spring servlet filter to authorize the request.

Need to add a filter in the spring security filter chain that updates the user with few details (re-loading permissions or anything) for every request, if they need to be changed.

Need some sample code snippet to follow or understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To add a custom filter you should extend the `org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean`, like so:

```
public class MySecurityFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response,
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The next step is to actually register the filter by overriding the `configure` method of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter(
          new MySecurityFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

As you can see the filter is added by adding the filter to the `HttpSecurity` object. The method that is used is the `addFilterAfter` which basically allocates your filter after the one that you provide in the second argument, in this example is the `BasicAuthenticationFilter`, so your filter will be executed after this one, in the spring secuirty chain of filters.

**Update**

Refer to [this](https://dzone.com/articles/simple-attribute-based-access-control-with-spring) link to personalize the authorization of your servlet. The method gives you an `Authentication` object, through which you can obtain your `User` object and perform additional checks.

Comment: Some says we need to create servlet filter to authorize the custom requirement for the user. Also says - security filter just authenticates the user, and servlet filter authorizes the request...Could you please confirm or updates the above code

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite get what you mean. Authentication is done using spring security chain filters, so if the user request is authenticated from any of the filters, they are authenticated. After authentication comes access control, if this is what you mean by authorization. Access control is defined based on roles. Every user has some role(s) associated and they are able to see/do what the role enables.

Comment: Authorization is custom it is based on various db values and not in general like following the role approach. Please help me with the servlet filter to authorize the custom requirement. 1. fetch user details 2. perform certain validations 3. then grant the permission or deny the permission

Comment: 1. Is the above code is related to Servlet filter? 2. Also the link you have mentioned doesn't have anything related to filtering the servlet. is this one is the right link to look into ?

Comment: Any comments @NiVer ? Please let me know

Comment: Tried to look up something for you and I think what you need is interceptors. They allow you to intercept a request right before and right after it is handled by their suitable handler. Check this out: https://www.boraji.com/spring-mvc-4-how-to-intercept-request-with-a-handlerinterceptor.